# Strange warning declaring a simple PyParsing recursive grammar in Python

Tags: python, recursion, grammar, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a CLIPS-like grammar in Python using PyParsing.

The piece of code I am having problem with is:

```
import pyparsing as pp

...some pyparsing tokens definitions...

INTEGER_EXPRESSION = EXPRESSION

RULE_NAME = SYMBOL

RULE_PROPERTY = OB + pp.Literal('salience') + INTEGER_EXPRESSION + CB

DECLARATION = OB + pp.Literal('declare') + pp.OneOrMore(RULE_PROPERTY) + CB

ACTION = EXPRESSION

CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT = pp.Forward()

TERM = CONSTANT | SINGLEFIELD_VARIABLE | MULTIFIELD_VARIABLE | pp.Literal(':') + FUNCTION_CALL | pp.Literal('=') + FUNCTION_CALL

SINGLE_CONSTRAINT = TERM | pp.Literal('~') + TERM

CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT << SINGLE_CONSTRAINT | SINGLE_CONSTRAINT + pp.Literal('&') + CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT

CONSTRAINT = pp.Literal('?') | pp.Literal('$?') | CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT

ORDERED_PATTERN_CE = OB + SYMBOL + pp.ZeroOrMore(CONSTRAINT) + CB

PATTERN_CE = ORDERED_PATTERN_CE

CONDITIONAL_ELEMENT = PATTERN_CE

DEFRULE_CONSTRUCT = OB + pp.Literal('defrule') + RULE_NAME + pp.Optional(COMMENT) + pp.Optional(DECLARATION) + pp.ZeroOrMore(CONDITIONAL_ELEMENT) + pp.Literal('=>') + pp.ZeroOrMore(ACTION) + CB
```

I have omitted the definition of some parts of the grammar because they are too long.

The problem is that the interpreter gives me this strange error:

SyntaxWarning: Cannot combine element of type  with ParserElement
  CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT << SINGLE_CONSTRAINT | SINGLE_CONSTRAINT + pp.Literal('&') + CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT

I have noticed that if I write:

```
CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT << SINGLE_CONSTRAINT
```

instead of:

```
CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT << SINGLE_CONSTRAINT | SINGLE_CONSTRAINT + pp.Literal('&') + CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT
```

It works without problems.

However even if I write something like this:

```
CONNECTED_CONSTRAINT << SINGLE_CONSTRAINT | pp.Literal('test')
```

It does not work.

So I suppose the problem is in having an OR, given by the "|" symbol, in a token declared with pp.Forward().

Could you help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! It was explained here: http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.Forward-class.html

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.

This kind of problem was explained here:

http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.Forward-class.html

I have to write expressions of the kind:

```
x << a | b
```

in this way:

```
x << (a | b)
```

because the operator "|" has lower precedence than the operator "<<".

Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hey, someone actually read the documentation! Welcome to pyparsing!

Comment: Thank you! Amazing library btw ;)